# Getting some message while activating a conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I've created a conda environment named `datascience` having important modules for data science like pandas, tensorflow etc. When activating the environment, I get something like `Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpwxx6gxkd.bat` before successful activation of the environment. Name of the `.bat` file changes every time when I try to activate the environment.

I think, for this reason only, I can't create Python interactive window/Jupyter code cells in vs code. VS code throws errors like,

```
StdErr from ShellExec, Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpfdkrke2b.bat 
Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpckuitzvd.bat for 
C:/Users/sivaram/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && 
python c:\Users\sivaram\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py 
c:/Users/sivaram/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
```

when creating a jupyter code cells/Python interactive window.

Comment: -How did you create this "conda" environment? And how did you try to activate it? Could you use "Python interactive window" and "Jupyter notebook" in other environments besides this environment?

Comment: I created the environment like, `conda create -n datascience ...` in Anaconda prompt. When activating the environment with `conda activate datascience` in Anaconda prompt itself, it successfully activated but leaves a [message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTBVWi7kHH5f0pLqoAs5AGDrHe2OCnES/view?usp=sharing). I've used "Jupyter notebook" with this environment only when activating with anaconda prompt not with VS code, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I used the method you described to create and activate the environment with the same name and it can be used normally. You could refer to this [link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8888) to check whether there are spaces or special symbols in the name of the relevant folder. In addition, please try to recreate the conda environment or reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: First I think the problem is with Anaconda itself. But, after trying it now, it suddenly works, that is the environment can be activated from the VS code. Thank you for your kind reply.